# Combining Few Rows of data in One ROW using Sum Function and not doing this for all the row

Tags: sql

Fiends Please help me with this ASAP. Really appreciate it thanks

I have  really simple table. Which as three columns

```
Col A                Col B                    Col C
(unique)nameA        (UniqueID)1              (somenumber)10  
(unique)nameB        (UniqueID)2              (somenumber)20 
(unique)nameC        (UniqueID)3              (somenumber)30 
(unique)nameD        (UniqueID)4              (somenumber)10 
(unique)nameE        (UniqueID)5              (somenumber)50 
(unique)nameF        (UniqueID)6              (somenumber)35 
(unique)nameG        (UniqueID)7              (somenumber)50 
(unique)nameH        (UniqueID)8              (somenumber)10     
(unique)nameI        (UniqueID)9              (somenumber)25
```

As per my report requirement i need to combine Unique ID (1,2,3) Give it a Unique name ALFA and Sum the Col C values  AND combine (4,5,6) Give it a Unique name BETA and Sum the Col C values for them
And keep other Unique ID, Unique Name and Their values in Col C as is
Order by values in Col C Desc and display TOP 30 results.

So Final result should look like this

```
Col A                Col B                    Col C
BETA                 (unique ID 4,5,6)        95              --(10+50+35 from col C 
ALFA                 (unique ID 1,2,3)        60              --(10+20+30 from col C above)    
above)
(unique)nameG        (UniqueID)7              (somenumber)50 
(unique)nameI        (UniqueID)9              (somenumber)25
(unique)nameH        (UniqueID)8              (somenumber)10
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You need to perferm something special on the 6 first rows, and return the rest normally !?!?

Comment: You mentionted that results should be ordered by col c descending but your example does not reflect this.  Was this a mistake?

Comment: @ billy- Yes I need to perform something special on the 6 first rows, and return the rest normally. Thanks. Yea it was a mistake for order by clause in example rest is same. Is it possible to use CASE Statements here?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  There is no reason you should not be able to use case statements.  How are you looking to use them?

Answer (score 0):

ould something like this work?

```
declare @simpletable table( name varchar(50), uniqueid int, somenumber int)
insert into @simpletable
select 'a', 1, 10
union all
select 'b', 2, 20
union all
select 'c', 3, 30
union all
select 'd', 4, 10
union all
select 'e', 5, 50
union all
select 'f', 6, 35
union all
select 'g', 7, 50
union all
select 'h', 8, 10
union all
select 'i', 9, 25

select top 30 name,uniqueid,somenumber
from
(
select 'ALFA' as name, '1,2,3' as uniqueid, sum(somenumber) as somenumber
from @simpletable
where uniqueid between 1 and 3
union all
select 'BETA' as name, '4,5,6' as uniqueid, sum(somenumber) as somenumber
from @simpletable
where uniqueid between 4  and 6
union all
select name as name, cast(uniqueid as varchar(50)) as uniqueid, somenumber as somenumber
from @simpletable
where uniqueid > 6
) as x
order by somenumber desc
```